# What exactly is a Redpost collection at surrender@20?

Tags: league-of-legends

I think maybe it is some kind of summary? But on the Red Post Collection Site there are also just news and stuff like that. So what exactly is a Redpost collection?

Comment: The point of the body is to expand on the title.  It's not just filler space.

Comment: I feel that it is unnecessary because of the simplicity of my question, but here you go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a RIOT employee posts something in the forums, their name comes up with a red font.

The "Red Posts" are collections of what RIOT employees have posted in the forums, denoting that this information came straight from them.